# Binding two List<String> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I have two list, which is meant to be presented in one DataGrid.

This code generates a InvalidOperationException:

This is my Properties section:

```
public List<String> Temperature;
public List<String> Time;
```

And how the lists are filled with data

```
Temperature = new List<string>(reader.GetTemperature());
Time = new List<string>(reader.GetTime());
```

How I bind to the DataGrid in C#

```
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = Temperature;
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = Time;
```

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgCsvData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200" Width="250" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Temperature}" Header="Temperature" IsReadOnly="True"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Header="Time" IsReadOnly="True" />
</DataGrid>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: checkout some of these as well as do a google search your code behind looks normal assuming it's populated with data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295522/want-to-bind-list-from-cs-file-to-grid-in-xaml-with-out-any-code-in-code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display time and temperature in pairs (in two columns), try this:

```
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = Time.Zip(Temperature, (t,c) => 
    new {Time = t, Temperature = c});
```

Using `Zip`, you pair up two sequences and create a new anonymously typed object using the pair. Then the DataGrid should be able to display each pair as a row using the bindings you defined in xaml.

---

You haven't wrapped the column definitions in `<DataGrid.Columns>...</DataGrid.Columns>`, so the columns you provide incorrectly get added to `DataGrid.Items`. Since you cannot set `DataGrid.Items` and `DataGrid.ItemsSource` at the same time, you get the `InvalidOperationException`.  To fix it:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgCsvData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200" Width="250" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Temperature}" Header="Temperature" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Header="Time" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: on which line do you get it exactly?

Comment: I get the error from this line: `dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = Time.Zip(Temperature, (t, c) => new { Time = t, Temperature = c });`

Comment: uh, I just noticed a bug in your XAML.  Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve something like the below code. Pls check this.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgCsvData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200" Width="250" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Temperature}" Header="Temperature" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Header="Time" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>            
    </DataGrid>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
        lst.Add(new MyClass() { Temperature = "60 F", Time = "2:30 PM" });
        lst.Add(new MyClass() { Temperature = "62 F", Time = "2:35 PM" });
        dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = lst;
    }        
}

class MyClass
{
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```